# Unknown report type: xlsx: - Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, xlsx, odoo-10

I am trying to create an `xlsx` report. I tried below code but getting an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/shar/Projects/git/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 72, in wrap
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/shar/Projects/git/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1485, in index
>       request.session.db, request.session.uid, request.session.password, report_id])
>     File "/home/shar/Projects/git/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 118, in dispatch_rpc
>       result = dispatch(method, params)
>     File "/home/shar/Projects/git/odoo/odoo/service/report.py", line 35, in dispatch
>       res = fn(db, uid, *params)
>     File "/home/shar/Projects/git/odoo/odoo/service/report.py", line 142, in exp_report_get
>       return _check_report(report_id)
>     File "/home/shar/Projects/git/odoo/odoo/service/report.py", line 120, in _check_report
>       raise UserError('%s: %s' % (exc.message, exc.traceback))
>   UserError: (u"Unknown report type: xlsx: (, NotImplementedError(u'Unknown report type: xlsx',), )", '')

Here is my code:

***.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo.addons.report_xlsx.report.report_xlsx import ReportXlsx

class PartnerXlsx(ReportXlsx):

    def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, partners):
        for obj in partners:
            report_name = obj.name
            # One sheet by partner
            sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(report_name[:31])
            bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
            sheet.write(0, 0, obj.name, bold)


   PartnerXlsx('report.module_name.res.partner.xlsx',
        'res.partner')
```

***.xml**

```xml
  <report
      id="partner_xlsx"
      model="res.partner"
      string="Print to XLSX"
      report_type="xlsx"
      name="res.partner.xlsx"
      file="res.partner.xlsx"
      attachment_use="False"
  />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems right, but remember that all other odoo rules still apply, don't forget to:

1. Add 'report_xlsx' as a dependency in _openerp_.py manifest
2. Add your .xml file in data dict inside _openerp_.py manifest ('data': ['report/file.xml'])
3. Add an __init__.py file with `from . import <report_file_name>` inside your report folder (where your .py file lies, and desirably, also your xml file, as declared on the manifest).
4. Add `from . import report` inside your addon __init__.py file
5. Update your addon inside odoo app.

Should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a report_type as *xlsx* format

we have only qweb-pdf,qweb-html,controller

report_type will accept anyone of these (*qweb-pdf,qweb-html,controller*)

It does not have *xlsx* as such

Please refer '*ir.actions.report.xml*' class for further reference

Comment: Could you check `report_xlsx` module available in odoo app store?

Comment: Have you given dependency?

Comment: Yes, i have added